# jquery question regarding text change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var text3;
        $('.HideButton').click(function () {


            text3 = $('#MessageText').text;

            var theButton = $(this);

            $('#disclaimer').slideToggle('slow', function () {
                theButton.val($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
            });


            $('<p>' + text3 + '</p>').addClass("new").insertAfter('#disclaimer');
            return false;



        });


    });
```

updated...code above doesnt change the buttons text

```
<p id="disclaimer" > DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</p>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="HideButton" runat="server" Text="Hide" />
```

I want the text of the button to change each time i press on it..But it doesnt

```
<p  id="disclaimer"  > 

    <input id="MessageText" type="text" />


</p>

<asp:Button ID="Button21" CssClass="HideButton" runat="server" Text="Hide" />
```

As message typed in the textbox..it should appear while "#disclaimer disappear

Comment: You completely changed your question.  Now there is a text box and an append?  What text box?

Comment: Your original question was answered a few different times and a couple different ways. Now you've asked what is essentially a completely new question.

I recommend any further changes be formed into their own questions.

Comment: +1 @kasdega this question has completely changed since we originally answered it and no longer makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The  will render out to a form element. This means you should use `.val()` instead of `.text()`

Also as Neil has pointed out, you are returning before this gets executed.

```
    $('.HideButton').click(function () {
        $('#disclaimer').slideToggle('slow');

        // return false;

        if ($('#disclaimer').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).val('Hide');

        } else {
            $(this).val('Show');

        }
    });
});

<p id="disclaimer" > DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</p>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="HideButton" runat="server" Text="Hide" />
```

Comment: If you down vote something please leave a note as to why you down voted it.

Comment: calling .text() on a button will not change the text displayed in that button.  using .val() will.  I don't understand the down vote here. http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/99GaJ/

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you returned before you canged any text.

remove the `return ...;` (or move it to the end of the function)

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false at the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

After return your code will never be executed. Try this

```
$('.HideButton').click(function () {
        var theButton = $(this);
        $('#disclaimer').slideToggle('slow', function(){
            theButton.val($(this).is(':visible')?'Hide':'Show');
        });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Nice clean code although cant you replace that `$(this)` in the middle with your cached copy?

Comment: $(this) inside slideToggle points to disclaimer div where as $this points to hideButton so we cannot use it :)

Comment: This will not change the text of the button when it's clicked.  Here's a JSfiddle variation that does...I too don't recommend using $this as a var name simply because it's confusing.  http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/99GaJ/

Comment: credit where credit is due.  this is mostly shankar's code he just needs to use .val instead of .text

Comment: The val doesnt work as expected..look above..what i tried to do in my new code

Comment: Dmitry this did answer your original question with the exception of the .val .text thing.  You completely changed your question now.

Comment: @Dmitry - Did changing the text to val helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Your original question was answered a few different times and a couple different ways.  Now you've asked what is essentially a completely new question.

I recommend any further changes be formed into their own questions.

Is this what you now want?

http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/99GaJ/1/